# How to make the slider of a Tkinter Scale widget start in certain place?

Tags: python, tkinter, slider, position, tkinter-scale

I am using the tkinter `Scale` widget and I have a scale set up from 0 to 200. When I open it up, I want the slider to be set at 100 (halfway on the trough) not 0. Is there a way for this to be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`tkinter.Scale.set`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm#Tkinter.Scale.set-method) method to set the scale to whatever value.

Below is a simple script to demonstrate:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Scale

root = Tk()

w = Scale(root, from_=0, to=200)
w.pack()
w.set(100)  # Set the initial value to 100

root.mainloop()
```

Example:

[image]